# Domain Controller unable to authenticate Static IP workstation/server

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory

I have an exchange server which was on a static IP (192.168.10.3) previously,  failed to communicate with my all-in-one domain controller (192.168.10.2) out of a sudden. The only way to get it working is to joined via DHCP and reserve the DHCP IP on the DC. Do anyone have any ideas of the possible cause of this issue?

Below are a list of actions I have tried to get it working again but to no avail:

1. Flush DNS cache and reset static IP
2. Manually added ﻿in the DNS sufffix with static IP configuration
3. Restarting the Network Location Awareness Service
4. Turning off IPV6
5. Using other Static IP that is within/out of the DHCP scope - both didn't
   work
6. Scavenge all DNS stale records

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was the Exchange server using for DNS? What is it using now?

Comment: Using my DC as the DNS server

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the reverse lookup zone of your DNS server for the presence of PTR-record for exchange server?
In the absence of this record, authorization may not pass.
When you joined your server via DHCP, PTR-record, probably, was created automatically.